# My database logs doesn't show a specific executed command

Tags: sql-server, log-analysis

I have a table in my database that I know a record deleted here definitely. (because of evidence of users and some of my application audit log)

I have tried to get information from logs via "SQL Log Analyzer" but it doesn't show that specific record insertion on deletion.

I definitely know that my record has inserted on a specific day between 2020-04-01 and 2020-04-23.

Whats wrong with logs? Is it possible that something missed in the database log and didn't save in database logs? (which would mean a violation of ACID).

[image]

Comment: It is HIGHLY unlikely that something went "wrong" or was "lost" by the database engine. Without any information all we can do is speculate and there is little reason to do that. Give the timespan you indicated and a single log file, i'll guess your database is set to simple recovery and the information you seek is no longer in that file - because that is how simple recovery works.

Comment: My database set to full recovery mode. But as you can see in my image my approximate timestamp is between the start and the end time that is shown in the image. I'm looking away to realize that happen.